# Is the order of arguments in a function call important?

Tags: c++, c, function, arguments

If in a function, the arguments are listed in a certain order

```
int foo( size_t bar, int baz )
{
  /* 
    Some very important  code here
  */
 return zap;
}
```

does it matter if I call it like:

```
size_t size = 16;
int op = 19;
foo( size, op );
```

Or

```
foo( op, size);
```

Comment: It depends, for commutative function  `constexpr int add(int a, int b) {return a+b;} static_assert(add(42, 58) == add(58, 42));` it is same, but for non commutative ones `constexpr int sum(int a, int b) {return a-b;} static_assert(sum(42, 58) == sum(58, 42));`. it is not the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it matters. The arguments must be given in the order the function expects them.

C passes arguments by value. It has no way of associating a value with an argument other than by position.

The names you use in the arguments passed to the function are irrelevant. C does not examine the argument names to figure out which parameters they should be associated with. Generally, arguments may be expressions, not just names, and an argument like `57` or `4+8` does not indicate which parameter it should be.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for this, other than the user?

Comment: @Jordan How do you expect the compiler to decide in which order it should map the arguments to parameters? Note that both `op` and `size` can be converted to `size_t` and `int`. So both orders are possible.

Comment: If both parameters are of the same type and are treated symmetrically, such as `int add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }`, then the order doesn't matter. But that's a rare case.

Comment: @Jordan You can also have multiple arguments of the same type. It would be impossible to discriminate between them if you discounted their order.

Comment: I remember the good old days of Pre-ANSI C. You could really have fun with the parameter ordering. And thinking on those times they really weren't all that good.